# Selenium: how to click on a button with the same class?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pytest

```
<div class="links-row">
<a href="https://example.com/manifest" target="_blank" class="blue-button">Manifesto</a> 
<a href="https://blog.example.com" target="_blank" class="blue-button">Example Blog</a> 
<a href="https://fale.example.com" target="_blank" class="blue-button">Fale com a gente</a> 
<a href="https://example.freshdesk.com/" target="_blank" class="blue-button">Ajuda</a></div>
```

current code:

```
test = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'blue-button')
test.click()
```

I wanna click on some buttons, but they all have the same class, so selenium only finds the first one with this name. How can I make it click on the other buttons?

I only found old examples with different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use **driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'blue-button')**.

This will give you a list of all buttons then you can click all of them using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The Css Selectors are

```
a[href*='example.com/manifest']
a[href*='blog.example.com']
a[href*='fale.example.com']
a[href*='example.freshdesk.com']
        
div.links-row > a:nth-child(1)
div.links-row > a:nth-child(2)
div.links-row > a:nth-child(3)
div.links-row > a:nth-child(4)
```

Comment: How does "div.links-row > a:nth-child(1)" translate to code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to locate the desired element using an XPath.

```
//a[text()='Manifesto']
//a[text()='Example Blog']
//a[text()='Fale com a gente']
//a[text()='Ajuda']
```

It makes them more "human readable" in that you can look at the locator and tell which link they are clicking on.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//a[@class="blue-button"])[1]')
```

Which would mean **"get the first 'a' where class is blue-button"**